# Render action with parameters after form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have basic form that is accessed, for example via: `http://url.com/rentals/new/dvd/10`.
The problem is when form error happens I can't redirect it to the same page with the same 
url segments and show the form error messages.

**rentals_controller.rb:**

```
def create
    @rental = Rental.new(rental_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rental.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rental, notice: 'Rental was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rental }
      else           
        format.html { render :new }            
        format.json { render json: @rental.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

**routes.rb**

```
get 'rentals/new/dvd/:dvd_id' => 'rentals#new', as: :new_dvd_rental
```

I have the following models created:
**dvd.rb**

```
class Dvd < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rentals
  has_many :users, through: :rentals

  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :year, inclusion: {in: 1900..Time.now.year.to_i}, :presence => {:message => 'Year must be from 1900 till current year.'}
  validates :length, inclusion: {in: 1..999}, :presence => {:message => 'DVD length must be in minutes in range 1..999.'}
end
```

**rental.rb**

```
class Rental < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :dvd
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :total_price, presence: true
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :rentals
  has_many :dvds, through: :rentals
end
```

As well as **rentals_controller.rb**:

```
class RentalsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_rental, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /rentals
  # GET /rentals.json
  def index
    @rentals = Rental.all
  end

  # GET /rentals/1
  # GET /rentals/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /rentals/new
  def new
    @rental = Rental.new
    @users = User.all
    @dvd = Dvd.find(params[:dvd_id])
  end

  # GET /rentals/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /rentals
  # POST /rentals.json
  def create
    @rental = Rental.new(rental_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @rental.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rental, notice: 'Rental was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rental }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rental.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /rentals/1
  # PATCH/PUT /rentals/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @rental.update(rental_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @rental, notice: 'Rental was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @rental }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @rental.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /rentals/1
  # DELETE /rentals/1.json
  def destroy
    @rental.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to rental_url, notice: 'Rental was successfully deleted.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_rental
      @rental = Rental.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def rental_params
      params.require(:rental).permit(:dvd_id, :user_id, :rent_date, :return_date, :total_price, :returned)
    end
end
```

I've tried to modify rental controller like this, but still do not know how to pass other segments like `new` and `dvd`:

```
render :action => "new", :dvd_id => params[:dvd_id]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think no need to pass params in render action, you can directly access the params[:dvd_id] on render view.

Comment: @Sanket - do you mean if you `render :new`, the `params` hash will be available in that view?

Comment: yes. Rich, you can access it.

Comment: @Bounce Dvd is your model? and Please give me your new action.

Comment: @Sanket, yes dvd is model. Please check updated question - added model listing.

Comment: Please give the rentals_controller new action, I think you create @dvd object in new which used for form object for routes, and its is missed in create method.

Comment: @Sanket, updated my question with full rentals_controller.rb code. Check it out.

Comment: add this line as first line of rentals controller create method " @dvd = Dvd.find(params[:dvd_id])" :)

note: please follow the routes as suggested by Waqar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think if you draw a more restful route like this

```
resources :dvds do
  resources :rentals
end
```

you will get the routes like `http://url.com/dvd/10/rentals/new`

here you will always get dvd_id

and in rentals_controller create method look like

```
def create
  @dvd = Dvd.find(params[:dvd_id])
  @rental = Rental.new(rental_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @rental.save
      format.html { redirect_to @rental, notice: 'Rental was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rental }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @rental.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Also, as Sanket mentioned, had to create new dvd in controllers create method: @dvd = Dvd.find(params[:rental][:dvd_id]). Now it works fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

-- Waiting for `@Sanket`'s ideas

**Routes**

The issue will almost certainly be with your `redirect_to` method

The problem is that your `controller` doesn't know you're using a [`nested resource`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), and consequently when you redirect to an object, it will likely just take you to the simplest route it can find

I would try this:

```
def create
      ...
      else           
        format.html { render your_nested_resource_path(dvd_id: params[:dvd_id], other: params[:params]) }
      ...
end
```

This allows you to send the request to the *nested* route, which Rails won't route to without support

Comment: Hey @Rich I did get your idea of 'render your_nested_resource_path(dvd_id: params[:dvd_id], other: params[:params])',when object has some error then we need to render same new action of same controller (most of time). so we can write like this {render :new }, please clarify me.

Comment: What I meant was the controller will not know about the `nested` route - so you'll have to point to the route explicitly I think

Comment: I think @Bounce has Dvd model, which is nested of Rental object and may be Bounce missed to create Dvd object in create method. so that is one the reason of 'form error'. What you think?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest - I'd love to hear `@bounce`'s ideas about it :)

Comment: Followed the @Sanket and Waqar suggestions. So created the new nested resource, as well as dvd object as Sanket offered. Now it works fine :) Rich was right about nested resources, but unfortunately this "your_nested_resource_path" (in my example new_dvd_rental_path) does not work with render. It throws an error about missing template.